# Is there a way to modify the corsera's Face recognition assignment?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, face-recognition

i tried to use the code provided in the course from coursera for face recognition to use it on an input image that i entered but it doesnt go well!

the code link:
https://www.coursera.org/learn/convolutional-neural-networks/programming/OgKZl/face-recognition/lab?path=%2Fnotebooks%2FW4A1%2FFace_Recognition.ipynb

1- i tried to append a new dictionary item with encoding function of my new image.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MXm5.png)

2- i tried to use who_is_it function on another img for the same person but the result is not what intended to be.
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH6xr.png)

Any help?

Comment: 1. Do not post screenshots of code or notebook cells. 
2. That model was trained on a specific set of images, it is not surprising that it won't work on a random image.

Comment: 1- Is it mean that i should train the model again on every new image ?

Comment: No, but it will recognize “similar” style images. If you have your own database, then yes you have to retrain it